# ReRender an uploaded image (a4j:mediaOutput)

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I would like to display an  uploaded image via ajax (in a a4j:mediaOuput tag) after uploading but I can't rerender the a4j:mediaOutput tag:

`<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <a4j:jsFunction name="refreshPic" reRender="picHolder" />
    <p:fileUpload mode="advanced" fileLimit="1" multiple="false"
        allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" auto="true"
        fileUploadListener="#{createSopController.fileChanged}"
        oncomplete="refreshPic()" />
    <a4j:outputPanel id="picHolder">
        <a4j:mediaOutput id="pic" element="img" cacheable="false"
            createContent="#{sessionImageBean.paint}"
            value="#{createSopBean.imageId}"
            mimeType="#{createSopBean.sop.mimeType}" width="672" height="1005"/>
    </a4j:outputPanel>
</h:form>`

Any ideas?

Comment: Might be a compatibility issue, is the function being executed at all?

Comment: The jsFunction is executed after the upload, but I can't rerender the a4j:mediaOutput tag...

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31395282/460557 Maybe it helps you solve your problem if it helps, don't forget to upvote ;)

Answer (score 1):

`a4j:mediaOutput` requires a varying request parameter, in order not to be cached. for this purpose, i prefer to use up-to-date timestamp from an application scoped managed bean. this is just like overcoming browser cache for js and css files, by appending timestamp parameter to their url.

btw, you don't need to to anything with this parameter when rendering the image.

```
<a4j:mediaOutput ... >
    <f:param value="#{appMB.timeStamp}" name="time" />
</a4j:mediaOutput>
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doens't work. Same problem. A manuell refresh (F5) works, but not automatically. Any other ideas?

Comment: you get the timeStamp from managed bean in milliseconds, right?

Comment: public long getTimeStamp(){ return System.currentTimeMillis(); }

Comment: could you try removing `a4j:outputPanel` and reRender directly "pic"?

Comment: can you add `prependId="false"` to `h:form`, and `execute="@this"` to `a4j:jsFunction`?

Comment: Same problem. Are there any other solutions?