# Not rerendering mediaOutput when upload file using richfaces 4

Tags: richfaces, ajax4jsf, rerender

I'm using richfaces 4 and JSF 2.1, in particular the tags ***rich:fileUpload*** and ***a4j:mediaOutput***. My goal is upload an image and preview it. I have the following code:

```
<rich:fileUpload id="upload" fileUploadListener="#{technicianBean.listener}" maxFilesQuantity="1" immediateUpload="true" ontyperejected="alert('Solo imágenes JPG');" acceptedTypes="jpg">

    <a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" render="info" />
    <a4j:ajax event="clear" listener="#{technicianBean.clearUploadData}" render="info" />

</rich:fileUpload>

<h:panelGroup id="info" layout="block" ajaxRendered="true" >
   <a4j:mediaOutput element="img" mimeType="image/jpeg" createContent="#{technicianBean.paint}"
     value="#{technicianBean.nickname}" style="width:100px; height:100px;" cacheable="false">
   </a4j:mediaOutput>
</h:panelGroup>
```

and

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class TechnicianBean extends PersonBean {

private String nickname;

private UploadedImage file;

public TechnicianBean() {
}

public String getNickname() {
    return nickname;
}

public void setNickname(String nickname) {
    this.nickname = nickname;
}

public UploadedImage getFile() {
    return file;
}

public void setFile(UploadedImage file) {
    this.file = file;
}


public void listener(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException {
    UploadedFile photo = event.getUploadedFile();
    file = new UploadedImage();
    file.setLength(photo.getData().length);
    file.setName(photo.getName());
    file.setData(photo.getData());
}

public void paint(OutputStream stream, Object object) throws IOException {
    if (file != null) { 
        stream.write(file.getData());
        stream.close();
    }       
    //stream.write(((UploadedImage) object).getData());
}

 public String clearUploadData() {
     file = null;
     return null;
 } 
}
```

The problem is in tag ***a4j:ajax event*** on ***render***, I think. For instance, my listener (clearUploadData) in ***a4j:ajax event="clear"*** executes the function but in both cases (*uploadcomplete* and *clear*) i'm not able to rerender the image (that is, the panelGroup with mediaOutuput inside) and when i delete or upload a new image anything is refreshed, even though if I refresh the page (F5) the content is properly showed.

I really don't know how to deal with it. Thanks in advance for your interest.

PS: The *value* (nickname) in the *a4j:mediaOputut* tag may confuse you, but in the paint function i'm writing in the stream the file attribute.

Comment: can you try the solution here? it seems not to work in that case, but i've seen it working for myself many times.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591407/rerender-an-uploaded-image-a4jmediaoutput/24825385

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31395282/460557 Maybe it helps you solve your problem if it helps, don't forget to upvote ;)